# Create a additional row from join sql?

Tags: sql, sql-server, join

I have 2 tables: Person and House with 1-n relation.
I want to the result return as picture below:

[image]

Row always have a Person column with a null House column.

Thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

you can use [unionall](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_ref_union_all.asp) to join the result set with person table something like

```
select p.name,h.name as housename from person p join house h on p.id=h.personid 
union all (select name,null from person)
order by name,housename
```

Comment: Thank you for your answer.  It is simpler than I thought.